# Copy interruption between hard drives

Tags: external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I'm transferring video files from 1 hard drive to another, if there was an interruption as in the hard drives couldn't be read and I had to click try again in Windows, is the quality still fine in the videos of the destination? Would there be missing scenes as a result of the interruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Again** tries the whole Copying of the file from start again, so if it has gotten over it is there as original.